# How do I see that for every point $(x,y,z)$ such that $||(x,y,z) - (0,1,0)|| = 1$ there exist $s \in \mathbb R$ s.t $\gamma(s) = (x,y,z)$?

Tags: geometry

I've the parametrization of a circle $\gamma(s)=(0,1,0) + \cos(s)(4/5,0,-3/5) + \sin(s)(0,-1,0)$.

I see that the radius is $1$ and that the center is $(0,1,0)$ (this is right?)

How do I see that for every point in space $\mathbb R^3$ of the form $(x,y,z)$ such that $||(x,y,z) - (0,1,0)|| = 1$ there exist $s \in \mathbb R$ s.t $\gamma(s) = (x,y,z)$ ?

That $\gamma(s)$ is included in the circle is easy to see by inspecting $||\gamma(s) - c||$.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true. There is no $s$ satisfying $\gamma(s) = (4/5,1,3/5)$.

Comment: So what I have is not a parametrization of a circle?

Comment: Yes, it is a parameterization of a circle. No, the set of points $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $\|(x,y,z) - (0,1,0)\| = 1$ is not a circle.

Comment: How do I see it is a complete circle and not "part of" a circle ?